# Is that possible that there are multiple codeowners files in a repository

Tags: github

I have a question, is that possible that there are multiple codeowners files in a repository?

the structure of repo looks like this:

```
/web
/src
/test
```

I have created a CODEOWNERS file under root repo

```
/web
/src
/test
CODEOWNDERS
```

It works perfectly.

Is that possible to create multiple codeowners file under /web and /src

```
/web
  CODEOWNDERS ---> for web
/src
  CODEOWNDERS ---> for src
/test
CODEOWNDERS
```

under Codeowners for web, it will be defined for web team.

Answer (score 0):

`CODEOWNERS` was [introduced in Nov. 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-11-12-code-review-assignment-beta/), and its [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) mentions only `CODEOWNERS` file per branch, not per folder.

> To use a `CODEOWNERS` file, create a new file called `CODEOWNERS` in the root, `docs/`, or `.github/` directory of the repository, in the branch where you'd like to add the code owners.
>
> Each `CODEOWNERS` file assigns the code owners for a single branch in the repository.
> Thus, you can assign different code owners for different branches, such as `@octo-org/codeowners-team` for a code base on the default branch and `@octocat` for a GitHub Pages site on the `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: but As I read this text, you can create a new file in root, or docs/. that means, you can create more than one files.

Comment: @user1938143 As I read it: it is an "exclusive or" : one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one CODEOWNERS file, but if I understand what you are getting at you can still have the behavior you want:

You can specify different "owners" per directories.  So your CODEOWNERS file could be something like this:

```
/web/ @web-team
/src/ @backend-team
```

Comment: non-ideal for distributed ownership of changing who owns code per department :( .  Instead 1 team is tasked with doing something they can't really do as it scales to be very very large repo across many departments.

Answer (score 0):

[CCODEOWNERS Bot](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/codeowners-bot) does this for you.  I have not tried it yet, but am hopeful.

A [feature request](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/21809) for this has been hanging since March 2020.